# Iterate over object properties with keys from second array

Tags: php, arrays, object, iterator

I would like to call a foreach loop on an object and iterate over `$this->_values`, but only for the keys that are present in `$this->_allowedFields`.

1) `$this->_values` *can* contain data that is not `$this->_allowedFields`, but should then be excluded from the foreach.

2) `$this->_allowedFields` *will* contain keys that are not in `$this->_values`, but I still need to include the step in the foreach loop.

**How can I achieve this?**

---

I have set up my class to implement Iterator and can successfully call a foreach loop on the object's _values array, like so:

```
foreach($object as $key => $value) {
    // do stuff
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Found the solution myself below when implementing the Iterator interface.

```
public function rewind()
{
    reset($this->_allowedFields);
}

public function current()
{
    $key = current($this->_allowedFields);
    return $this->_values[$key];
}

public function key()
{
    $key = current($this->_allowedFields);
    return $key;
}

public function next()
{
    next($this->_allowedFields);
    $key = current($this->_allowedFields);
    return $this->$this->_values[$key];
}

public function valid()
{
    $key = current($this->_allowedFields);
    $var = ($key !== null && $key !== false);
    return $var;
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something here but why don't you just loop over `$this->_allowedFields`?

Comment: @billyonecan because the data is actually held in _values

Comment: Right, but if the keys in `_allowFields` exist in `_values`, you can access them? (I don't know what either look like but wouldn't something like `$this->_values[$key]` work?)

Comment: I can access them. `$this->_values` works, and is what I am using for the moment, but I don't know the keys, hence I use a foreach. See my updated post for a bit more details to what I have now.

Comment: I could, but I am then iterating over values that I should not (I just want to iterate over the values in `$this->_values` that are present in `$this->_allowedFields`). If `_allowedFields = {'a','b'}` and `_values = {'a'=>1, 'c'=>3}` I want the resulting foreach loop to return 1.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. My approach was correct, but I had to change from key($this->_allowedFields) to current($this->_allowedFields) to correctly return the actual key for use in $_values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood u correct, than:
Can't you just check all values or all fields?
It's simple!

1) Way

```
foreach($objects as $key => $object){
foreach($object->_allowFields as $allowField){
    if(isset($object->_values[$allowField])){
        echo $object->_values[$allowField];
    }else{
        echo "Sorry, but this field is empty";
    }
}
```

}

2) Way #2

```
foreach($objects as $key => $object){
$allowedFields = $object->_allowFields;
foreach($object->_values as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($key, $allowedFields)){
        // Field is allowed
    }else{
        // FIeld not allowed
    }
}}
```

Comment: This would work of course, but I am looking to use the Iterator interface so that I can simply call `foreach($object as $key => $value) {//do stuff}`. I would otherwise need to repeat the above several times.

Comment: @birdieblue can u describe the algorythm of your mind? How do you see it? Because I dont understand (

Answer (score 0):

if you have the name of a class attribute like for example

```
class Car{
public $doors = 4;

}
```

then you can have the name `doors` in a variable, then call it like

```
$text = 'doors';
$car = new Car();
$numberOfDoors = $car->{$text}; // this is like calling $car->doors
```

then you can make your own loop with variable names

Comment: I need to use a foreach as I don't know what values have been set, and what values are allowed for a specific object, as such I can't hardcode to look for 'doors'.